# Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools Requires SetUp Packages

Tags: python, alpaca

I am trying to pip install alpaca-trade-api, but it says I need build tools.

When I try to download the build tools, it's asking for setup packages?

What are these packages and how do I download them, or is there an alternative solution?

Thank you